# How can I reduce my php code to loop my html table code?

Tags: php, mysql

I am hoping someone can help me with my php coding. Here is what I am attempting to do:

I run a video game club at my high school and we have 121 members this year (biggest club in a school of ~900 students). Retrogaming has been a hit with many of them and it had led to the discussion of having leaderboards. So early on I realized that constantly updating an HTML file would be rediculous and decided to setup a mysql database where high score attempts could be entered into a form (by me only) and populated to a webpage. Said webpage has a table for each game title, along with top 3 scores in the database. This part is working very well so far. My database schema goes something like this:

Table 1 ("gamesystems"):

- gamesystems_id (primary key, AI)
- gamesystems (varchar(30)) (e.g. Atari 2600, NES, Colecovision, etc.)

Table 2: ("games")

- games_id (primary key, AI)
- gamesystems_id (foreign key)
- game (varchar(30)) (e.g. Frogger, Crazy Taxi, etc)

Table 3: ("solo_leaderboard")

- id (primary key, AI)
- gamesystem (varchar(30))
- game (varchar(30))
- name (varchar(30))
- score (int(10))
- date (date)
- gradelevel (varchar(5)) (varchar is to accomidate N/A if not a student)
- whois (enum('student', 'teacher', 'administrator', 'other'))

Okay. Perhaps not perfect, but this schema works for now. I can add data and pull data, and post it to my php page on my website. Below is the code for just 2 games that I have posted right now. The issue should be obvious; I have to add 30+ lines of code for each new game that I want to post the high scores for. This is rediculous. I don't have a strong mysql or php background, but I spent a lot of time coding C++ and Python years and years ago. I think that there should be a way to have a NESTED loop that pulls each gaming system (table 1) one-by-one and creates a table for each game (table 2) for said system and populates the webpage with the top 3 scores from the solo-leaderboard (table 3). Unfortunately, I don't know how to make this happen. That is why I am here. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="strickho_leader";
$password="***********";
$database="strickho_leaderboards";

echo "
<body style='background-color:powderblue'; 'text-align:center';>
<h1 style='color:black'; 'font-size:300%'; 'text-align:center';>Benton Central M.A.G.I. Gaming Leaderboard</h1>
</body>";

//Create Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

//FREEWAY
//*****************************************
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM solo_leaderboard WHERE game LIKE '%Freeway%' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3");

echo "<table style='text-align:center'; border='1';>
<tr>
<th colspan='5'>Freeway</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan='5'><img src='https://www.mobygames.com/images/covers/l/20735-freeway-atari-2600-front-cover.jpg' height='200' width='145'></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Score</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Grade</th>
<th>Role</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><b>" . $row['score'] . "</b></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['gradelevel'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['whois'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table><br><br>";
//*******************************************
//END FREEWAY


//CRAZY TAXI
//*****************************************
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM solo_leaderboard WHERE game LIKE '%Crazy Taxi%' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3");

echo "<table style='text-align:center'; border='1';>
<tr>
<th colspan='5'>Crazy Taxi</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan='5'><img src='https://www.mobygames.com/images/covers/l/5801-crazy-taxi-dreamcast-front-cover.jpg' height='200' width='200'></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Score</th>
```

Comment: perhaps better for code review SE

Comment: Welcome to SO, the advice I would give is to set up your tables so that they have a relationship with one another. what I mean by that is have your tables like **games** table and **solo_leaderboard** call each other through a unique identifier that references both tables. This way, you are removing duplicate data, and all your tables would be linked to each other. @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs is kinda right in saying this is better for code review, because this is quite a broad topic, but I upvoted this question, because you show the willingness to learn :)

Comment: You can accomplish what you are looking for by editing your tables to have foreign keys and having join queries in your php code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making one query per game, you could make one general query that retrieves data for all games and then loop through it. It's two queries actually but those two queries should handle all the work. My proposal requires some changes to your tables, I'll walk you through it.

FIRST QUERY:

```
SELECT * from games
```

Just the `games` table. Nothing else. 
Then take that result (it'll be one game per row) and loop through it with a foreach:

```
foreach ($games as $game)
```

(I used `$games`, but use the variable with actually gets the query result)
Now that you're looping through the games, make a second query (within the loop) to get the leaderboard for that specific game.

SECOND QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM solo_leaderboard WHERE game LIKE '%game_name_from_previous_query%' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3
```

My suggestion here is not to search using `LIKE` as it is less efficient, even though it will work. My suggestion would be to alter the `solo_leaderboard` table to include the game id so you can search with `WHERE game_id = the_id_from_the_previous_query`

Finally, without exiting the outermost foreach loop, you can loop through the second query's results and draw the table as you are doing now.

That's the general idea. This will loop through all the games, get each game's leaderboard and output it to a table, then move on to the next game and so on

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I used PHP, but I will try to help, it's possible I misspell some PHP terms or functions.

First advice, it's better to write html static content directly instead of doing `echo`, every piece of php code you write is going to be processed by your server, an `echo` has low impact but 1k's of long html `echo` are worst than zero. So, instead of:

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="strickho_leader";
    $password="***********";
    $database="strickho_leaderboards";

    echo "<body style='background-color:powderblue'; 'text-align:center';>
<h1 style='color:black'; 'font-size:300%'; 'text-align:center';>Benton Central M.A.G.I. Gaming Leaderboard</h1>
</body>";

    //Create Connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

You should do:

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="strickho_leader";
    $password="***********";
    $database="strickho_leaderboards";
?>

<body style='background-color:powderblue'; 'text-align:center';>
<h1 style='color:black'; 'font-size:300%'; 'text-align:center';>Benton Central M.A.G.I. Gaming Leaderboard</h1>
</body>

<?php
    //Create Connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

And If you are using a nice web development editor you will get html syntax highligth in this way. When you have to print `php` values inside `html` code you can open an `php` code tag and make a single var `echo`.

Starting with your answer, of course you can make nested loops. First of all, I think you should change your data model, if leaderboards are different for everygame you should have `games_id` in the leaderboard table instead of game name.

So your code could look like this:

```
<?php
    $LEADER_TOP = 3;
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="strickho_leader";
    $password="***********";
    $database="strickho_leaderboards";
?>

<body style='background-color:powderblue'; 'text-align:center';>
<h1 style='color:black'; 'font-size:300%'; 'text-align:center';>Benton Central M.A.G.I. Gaming Leaderboard</h1>

<?php
    //Create Connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    /* Check connection (from docs) */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connection error: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    //All games
    $query = "SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY game ASC";

    if ($games = $mysqli->query($query)) {

        // Get single game
        while ($game = $games->fetch_assoc()) {         
            // Print game table
?>

<table style='text-align:center'; border='1';>
    <tr>
        <th colspan='5'><?php echo $game['game']; ?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan='5'><img src="<?php echo $game['image']; ?>" height='200' width='145'></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
        <th>Role</th>
    </tr>

<?php
            // Get leaders
            $query = "SELECT * FROM solo_leaderboard WHERE game_id = '"+ $game['games_id'] +"' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT "+$LEADER_TOP;
            if ($leaders = $mysqli->query($query)) {
                while ($leader = $leaders->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $leader['name']; ?></td>
        <td><b><?php echo $leader['score']; ?></b></td>
        <td><?php echo $leader['date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $leader['gradelevel']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $leader['whois']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
                } // END While Leaders

                // Free leaders
                $leaders->free();
            }
?>
</table><br><br>
<?php
        } // END While Games

        // Free games
        $games->free();
    }
?>
```

As you can see, you need to add the image url to your game model and change the game name to `games_id` in leaderboards.

Another personal advice, use always doubleqoute in html attributes: `src="xxx"`.

Good luck!